# Store multiple audio files in single directory- Android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder

**I am trying to build an android audio recorder app, where the audio recordings should be stored in a directory within my phone internal storage.**

This is my code in Android Studio:

```
File  AudioDir=new File("/sdcard/Audiofiles/");
AudioDir.mkdir();
String filename="recording.mp3";
output  = new File(AudioDir.getAbsolutePath(), filename);
output.createNewFile();
```

This code stores a single audio file in `Audiofiles` folder and overwrites the new audio recording.
I am getting the latest recording with the name `recording.mp3`.
The old ones are gone.

**I want multiple recordings to be stored within the same directory.** 
I tried coding it, but could not find any success. Please help.

**This is the code I wrote :**

```
   AudioDir=new File("/sdcard/Audiofiles/");
   AudioDir.mkdir();
   File output=null;

   Boolean flag=false;
   String filename=null;
   File file[]=AudioDir.listFiles();

       for(int i=0;i<file.length;i++)
       {
           if (file[i].equals(filename))
              flag=true;
           else
              flag=false;
       }

       if(flag==true)
       {
           System.out.println(i +" :flag==true");
           filename="recording"+i+".mp3";
           output  = new File(AudioDir.getAbsolutePath(), filename);
           output.createNewFile();

       }
       else if(flag==false)
       {
           System.out.println(i +" :flag==false");
           filename="recording"+i+".mp3";
           output  = new File(AudioDir.getAbsolutePath(), filename);
           output.createNewFile();
           i++;

       }
```

Now, what happens is that, I get files with unique names in the folder.. Cool..!!
But, once i close the app, and open it again and record the audio, the previous files get **overwrites**.. I don't want that to happen.
I need all the files.. What should I do ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your files are overwritten because they have the same name. You must provide a different name for each one you save, for example "recording" + a timestamp + ".mp3".

Comment: Plz suggest a solution for the new problem.

Comment: You are not using timestamps in the file name. By using timestamps you are guaranteed unique names, therefore none of your files will be overwritten. Instead of filename="recording"+i+".mp3"; please use filename="recording" + new Date().toString() + ".mp3";